# Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I've been working on a personal project and I'm having some issues regarding selenium and internet explorer finding elements.

Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import time

class Items(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie('IEDriverServer.exe')
        self.driver.get('https://www.freeip.com')

    def test_view_score(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('randomKEY')
        time.sleep(7)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My problem is that is: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with id == username`

I cannot figure out it cannot find the element on the website (does not work either for `id` or `name`) or maybe there is a frame I am not seeing?

Comment: Have you tried waiting for username to be visible?

Comment: You suggest i should try adding time.sleep() right above the find_element_by_id function?

Comment: No, sleeps are generally a bad practice. Add an explicit wait instead. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: I've been trying to make it work with explicit waits, but it does not work :(